# C how to "hide" macros from main scope

Tags: c, inheritance, struct, scope, unions

if have a routine like this which I want the main application to access...

```
    char* get_widget_name(widget_t* w) {
        return name(w);
    }
```

both the following macro's I want to "hide" while obviously using within get_widget_name

```
    #define GET_WIDGET(self) (&(self)->base.widget)
    #define name(self)      (GET_WIDGET(self)->name)
```

I'm basically using unions in structures to "emulate" c++ inheritance in C.

Comment: Do you mean `#undef MACRO_NAME`?

Comment: Scoping rules don't apply to macros. A macro can be used anywhere within a source file from the `#define` until either it's `#undef`ed or the end of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You publish the information to be used in the main application in a header file.  In this example, it might be:

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H_INCLUDED
#define WIDGET_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct widget widget_t;

extern char *get_widget_name(widget_t *w);

#endif /* WIDGET_H_INCLUDED */
```

And then in the implementation file (`widget.c`), you define the structure contents and the macros and use them as you see fit, without making them available to the main application at all.

Comment: yep! that does the trick! I was going to split them into includes later so would have fixed my own problem!